# How to Implement Dynamic Parallelism/Multi-threading to C language Routine?

Tags: dynamic, parallel-processing

I have required a C function/routine in DataStage to parse the `Arg1` based on `Arg2` and then it should return the resultant value. Here the `Arg1` is nothing but Transformlogic and `Arg2` is input values of the `Arg1`. Below is the function:

```
char* TransformParsing(char* Arg1, char* Arg2) 
{ 
..... 
parsing.. 
... 
.... 
return result; 
}
```

And I have an input record which has 4 columns separated by `|` like below:

```
KeyCol | TransformLogic1|TransformLogic2|TransformLogic3 
100|"if Col49[1,4]=COMM then I else P"|"if Col49[1,4]=COMM then Commission else Polo"|"if Col49[1,4]=COMM then ABC else xyz" 
101|TfL1|TfL2|TfL3 
102|TfL1|TfL2|TfL3
```

Here I have 3 TransformLogics in a 1st row (i.e., `KeyCol=100`). Now I want to process the entire row at the same time. The above routine can returning the result when I use in 1 column by making remaining 2 columns as dummy, like below:

```
KeyCol, TransformParse(Arg1, Arg2), "Dummy", "Dummy" --->is executing perfectly.
```

If we want to process the entire row we should have to call the routine at the same time in 3 places. When I call the function in many times it is simply keep on running/ hanging. 
So that's what I would like to go for Multi-Threading.

Like below:

```
KeyCol, TransformParse(Arg1, Arg2), TransformParse(Arg1, Arg2), TransformParsing(Arg1, Arg2).---> Is not executing perfectly
```

Now I hope I am very much clear about my aim. Now could anyone please understand my task and help me the same?